# Retrieving Pixels from a DNG file within Android

Tags: android, pixel, dng

I am currently working on an HDR application that requires the use of Camera2 to be able to customize HDR settings.

I have developed a customized algorithm to retrieve certain data from Raw DNG images and I would like to implement it on Android.

I am unfortunately not an expert in Java/Android, so I taught myself how to code. Using other formats, I have usually worked with bitmaps to retrieve pixel data. ( which was relatively an easy task concerning the existing methods )

Concerning DNG files, I have found no documentation showing me how to retrieve the pixels data. I thought of bufferizing the image, however the DNG file format contains many information other than pixels and I'm afraid I am unable to find an extraction strategy using bufferstream. (I just want to store the pixels inside an array)

Anyone has an idea ? Would highly appreciate some tips.

Best regards

Comment: Your question needs more detail - are you reading DNG images from disk? Where are the images coming from in the first place? Or are you reading RAW images from the camera2 API? In the latter case, you won't have a DNG file at all.

Comment: Hello,first of all thank you for the reply. What we are doing is : We use camera 2 api to retrieve the images. We do get 2 types of files for the same image : DNG and JPEG. I want to use the DNG file. I just want to retrieve the pixels for the image from that specific file. Let's suppose I'm getting my DNG files from an outer source, what would the solution be to load the pixels ? I am currently forced to convert DNG files to Bitmap, and then applying grayscale. I do not want that.

Comment: Camera2 does not produce DNGs directly - it produces plain RAW buffers, which you can then save to a DNG via DngCreator.  Are you operating on the initial RAW buffers, or saving DNGs and then loading them back? In general, DNGs are not full baked images, so quite a bit of code is needed to render them completely - see for example Adobe's DNG SDK (https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html)

Comment: I am very grateful for that link! How can I upvote you ?

Comment: Moved text to an answer, now that it's more clear what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera2 does not produce DNGs directly - it produces plain RAW buffers, which you can then save to a DNG via DngCreator.

Are you operating on the initial RAW buffers, or saving DNGs and then loading them back?

In general, DNGs are not full baked images, so quite a bit of code is needed to render them completely - see for example [Adobe's DNG SDK](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's not a direct answer, but it does lead me to one. To clarify, I am in charge of operating the hdr algorithm. I'm not in charge of the capture. I am receiving directly via another application that my colleague made, DNG file formats. I could ask him to just simply send me the Raw files instead, or I could use your link to comprehend how DNG files are encoded and be able to create my proper extraction algorithm.